# Adding a data attribute(with special characters) to a dom element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to add a data attribute to a html element. The data attribute(data-description) can contain special characters like apostrope.

```
InsertHtml = InsertHtml + '<tr id="DashboardRow0" data-description=\'' + JSON.stringify(data[0])+ '\'><td>' + </td></tr>';
htmlElement.append(InsertHtml);
```

The code to access this data is given below...

```
var $row = $("#DashboardRow0");
var jsonData = eval('(' + $row.attr('data-description') + ')');
```

But the problem is...If there is a single apostrophe within `JSON.stringify(data[0])` data..the browser replaces it with a `"` effectively terminating the string.

Is there any know solution to adding data attributes with special characters to nodes?

Comment: That eval hurts my eyes.

Comment: try to avoid eval if possible , did you try jquery.metada plugin if it has any options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try to escape data before stringify

```
data[0].myProblemField = escape(data[0].myProblemField)
JSON.stringify(data[0])
```

<edit>
   or better

```
 for(var prop in data[0]) if(typeof(data[0][prop]) == "string") 
   data[0][prop] = escape(data[0][prop]);
```

</edit>

and afterwards

```
var jsonData = eval('(' + $row.attr('data-description') + ')');
jsonData.myProblemField = unescape(data[0].myProblemField)
```

Comment: Great solution, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure whether this'll help you (i.e. whether this is all happening in the same document), but have you considered using jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)? It won't have these problems, as the data is stored as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you write in html

```
<tr id="some &quot; "><td>...</td></tr>
```

You get

```
<tr id="some " "><td>...</td></tr>
```

in browser.